# error of run scala code

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
package db
import com.mongodb.casbah.{ MongoCollection, MongoConnection, MongoDB }
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{ MongoDBObject }

object Test {
    def main(argc: Array[String]) {
        val db = MongoDB(MongoConnection(), "test")
        val objText = MongoDBObject("user" -> "This the text is test number the two")
        val coll = db.getCollection("coll_tet")
        coll.insert(objText)
        print(coll.find()) 
    }
}
```

And I do `scalac -classpath ... test.scala`

When I tried to run this: `scala db.Test -classpath ...` I'm get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/Mongo

Why is this happening?

Comment: `db.Test` should be after all options. May help if you post your entire command line and indicate if you're win32 or unix.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Of course, here is the full command line(win32): F:\test>scala -cp casbah-commons_2.8.1-2.1.2.jar;casbah-core_2.8.1-2.1.2.jar;casbah-gridfs_2.8.1-2.1.2.jar;casbah-query_2.8.1-2.1.2.jar;joda-time-1.6.jar;mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar;scalaj-collection_2.8.0-1.0.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar;time_2.8.0-0.2.jar db.Test

Comment: I think your command line is not referencing the jar path properly. `NoClassDefFoundError` is reported when the JVM can't find the class. The `-cp` option is relative to your current directory. So the way you run it currently assumes all the jars are in the current directory. Is that the case? If you run `dir` msdos command, it will show all the jars and the `db` directory (where `Test.class` is located).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the `Imports` object?

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
```

And it should take care of all your import problems.

Comment: If i just add         `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._` so i get this error         `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/casbah/BaseImports`

Comment: Do you have your jars in the same folder as your class?

Comment: Yes, jars have place to same directory.